# In Google Script, MailApp.sendEmails() and GmailApp.sendEmails() is not working. Any suggestions to fix or work around?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Whenever I use either MailApp or GmailApp in my Google Script, it does not work.  I have tested both of these with other functions such as retrieving mail and creating a draft.  It seems as if MailApp and GmailApp does not want to connect to my Gmail account.  I am programming this script in a Google Spreadsheet. I did get the .sendEmails() to work once, but have not been able to replicate the scenario. Here is the final product that should work:

```
function onEdit(e){
var date = new Date()
var time = ":" + date.getMinutes()
var hours24 = date.getHours() + 1; // retrieve current hours (in 24 mode)
var dayMode = hours24 < 12 ? "am" : "pm"; // if it's less than 12 then "am"
var hours12 = hours24 <= 12 ? (hours24 == 0 ? 12 : hours24) : hours24 - 12;
// "0" in 24-mode now becames "12 am" in 12-mode – thanks to user @Cristian
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('J2').setValue(date);
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('J3').setValue(hours12 + time +        dayMode);


var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
var mycell = ss.getActiveSelection();
  var cellrow = mycell.getRow();  
  var cellcol = mycell.getColumn();

var range = sheet.getRange(cellrow,cellcol); 
var data = range.getValue();

    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('K3').setValue("pass");

if( cellrow >= 2){
    var currinv = sheet.getRange(cellrow, 5)
    var plusinv = currinv.getValue() + data;
    var minusinv = currinv.getValue() - data;
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('K4').setValue("pass");
if(cellcol == 7) {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(cellrow,5).setValue(plusinv);
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(cellrow,7).setValue("");
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('J4').setValue(cellcol);
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('K5').setValue("pass");
}

if(cellcol == 9) {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(cellrow,5).setValue(minusinv);
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(cellrow,9).setValue("");
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('J5').setValue(cellcol);
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('K6').setValue("pass");
}

}
 var rowcurr = 2
 var rowcheck = currinv.getValue() 
 if(rowcheck == 1){
 SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('K7').setValue("pass");
 var recipient = "someone@example.com";
   var subject = "Test Email Alert System: Toner Inventory";
   var body = "This is a test email from the Toner Invenoty Alert System";

  MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, body)

  //or in case MailApp doesn't work anymore

  //GmailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, body)

 }
 }
```

Comment: You can't send a email from a simple trigger `onEdit()` function.  There are restrictions on the `onEdit()` simple trigger.  [Documentation - Restrictions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/#restrictions)  You need to used an installed edit trigger.  [Link Installable triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)

Comment: In that case I know there is a sendEmail() trigger that should definitely allow it.  How would I send cell information gathered from the onEdit() trigger and have it sent to the sendEmail() to be used in the body of the email.

Comment: Actually thank you for those link.  I looked into the installable triggers and was able to give the onEdit() trigger authorization and I am up and running thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Actually thank you for those link.  I looked into the installable triggers and was able to give the onEdit() trigger authorization and I am up and running thank you.